# How to find the distance between a value and the subsequent occurrence of the same value in a vector?

Tags: r

I have a vector in R that looks like this:

`dat <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)`

What I would like to calculate is the distance between a particular value and the subsequent occurrence of the same value. In the example I look for the subsequent occurrence of "TRUE" and I would like the resulting vector to be:

`dat1 <- c(1, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA)`

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I think `rle(X)` might be useful as well.  `foo<-rle(X)` followed by `bar <- foo[foo[1,]==FALSE,2]` or something like that (`foo` contains the values and the runlengths but I forget in which order).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why the NA values at the end?

You can get -in this case- the correct answer by:

```
> diff(which(X))
[1] 1 3
```

or, for the FALSE values :

```
> diff(which(!X))
[1] 1 2
```

You can then add as many NA values as you like, or predefine a vector, eg :

```
> result <- rep(NA,6)
> tmp <- diff(which(X))
> result[seq_along(tmp)] <- tmp
> result
[1]  1  3 NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much - you are obviously right, I don't need the NAs. I thought they would clarify my question.